# Cannot open remote file with TRAMP

Tags: tramp

I'm trying to connect and edit files on my openwrt box.
But every time I tried Emacs shows me a blank buffer.

```
C-x C-f /ssh:user:192.168.200.1:/etc/config/network RET
```

the filesystem on openwrt

```
cat /proc/filesystems 
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   ramfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   debugfs
nodev   securityfs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   bpf
nodev   pipefs
nodev   devpts
    squashfs
nodev   jffs2
nodev   overlay
```

edit: Hi I did a typo on the original question.

I've use this
/ssh:user@192.168.200.1:/etc/config/network

same error.

If I use /ssh:root@192.168.200.1:/etc/config/ 
I get into dired mode but when I select the file again blank buffer.

Doing the same on the terminal outside emacs all works.

Comment: Hi I did a typo on the original question. I've use this
/ssh:user@192.168.200.1:/etc/config/network

same error.
If I use /ssh:root@192.168.200.1:/etc/config/ 
I get dired mode but when I select the file blank buffer

Comment: Do you get the same result if you use SCP instead of SSH? e.g. `C-x C-f /scp:user@192.168.200.1:/etc/config/network RET`

Comment: Doing SCP it gives me the file as expected.

Comment: But no with SSH and I wonder why?

Comment: Not sure but I have a couple guesses. I’ve noticed the same symptoms when files are large or compressed but I’ve also wondered if this was I use cygwin + emacs. I don’t recall if I’ve seen the symptoms outside of cygwin.

Comment: I added my suggestion as answer since it resolved the symptoms but not the underlying issue.

Comment: is there any info in your \*messages\* buffer?

Answer (score 0):

It is the wrong syntax. Use `/ssh:user@192.168.200.1:/etc/config/network`

Comment: I wonder why he just gets a blank buffer, tho.

Comment: He will get an error message. The blank buffer represents a non-existing (new) file.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try switching to different protocol, e.g. `ssh` to `scp`

For example,

`/ssh:username@hostname:/path/`

would become

`/scp:username@hostname:/path/`

> **Tip:** Another advantage of switching from `ssh` to `scp` is improved uploading and downloading times for larger files. However I don’t think you can use `scp` with the `TRAMP` [multi-hops](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Multi_002dhops.html) feature.